# Создание MessageBox при получение сигнала клиентом C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

Как сделать так чтобы по нажатию кнопки на сервере посылался сигнал клиенту, а тот в свою очередь при получении сигнала создавал MessageBox?

Comment: Слишком общий вопрос. Я бы использовал TCP-пакеты. На стороне клиента создайте фоновую задачу, которая будет слушать TCP-порт, и если определенный пакет пришел на порт, создаем `MessageBox`. На стороне сервера по нажатию кнопки отправляйте TCP-пакет на endpoint клиента

Comment: Гм. Клиент должен тем или иным образом подключиться к серверу. После этого сервер сможет посылать клиенту сообщения, а тот будет на них реагировать. Как именно - зависит от множества вопросов: какую платформу вы используете, какие технологии можете взять, может ли клиент опрашивать сервер или обязательна инициатива самого сервера и пр. Смотрите [Sockets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/sockets), [SignalR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/), [WebSockets](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.websockets?view=net-5.0).